# C# (Xamarin iOS) How to loop son data on Custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Any Help will be appreaciated :) Thank you in advance
I tried to loop other object inside of the function and its working but on this, it can't loop. Help. this is rush, and I'm not that familiar with creating iOS app.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();



        using (var web = new WebClient())
        {
            var url = "http://www.creativeinterlace.com/smitten/maintenance/api/feeds/get-miss-location/101";
            json = web.DownloadString(url);

        }
        json = json.Replace("{\"location\":", "").Replace("}]}", "}]");
        var ls = JArray.Parse(json);
        if (ls.Count != 0)
        {

            foreach (var x in ls)
            {
                var name = x.SelectToken("location");
                 name1 = Convert.ToString(name);

                var loc = x.SelectToken("address");
                 loc1 = Convert.ToString(loc);

                var time = x.SelectToken("time_ago");
                 time1 = Convert.ToString(time);

              locations = new List<Locations>
                {

                   new Locations
                    {

                        shopname = name1,
                        address= loc1,
                        time = time1
                    },   
                };

            }

            nmtable.Source = new LocationSource(locations);
            nmtable.RowHeight = 60;
            nmtable.ReloadData();


        }

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean not looping? foreach is a loop. It is looping. Need more details about when and how its not working

Comment: yeah thats the thing, the code was located inside the foreach loop but it didn't affect the code. it still showing only the first record.

Its supposed to be show two tableviewcell because the json I used was have 2 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize the locations every time in the loop,so the list updates with only the newest object. You should initialize the list outside of the loop , and add object every time.

```
locations = new List<Locations>();

if (ls.Count != 0)
{
     foreach (var x in ls)
     {
           var name = x.SelectToken("location");
           name1 = Convert.ToString(name);

           var loc = x.SelectToken("address");
           loc1 = Convert.ToString(loc);

           var time = x.SelectToken("time_ago");
           time1 = Convert.ToString(time);

           locations.Add(new Locations{ shopname = name1,address= loc1,time = time1});
     };

}
```

Comment: Thank You Mr.Cole Xia!!!!
It works like a charm!!!! I Owe you my whole day task :D

Comment: @KimsonMagat glad to help you, consider accepting it as answer,Thanks.